# Is it wise to invest in SSD(32gb)+ hdd and windows8 or just HDD?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

I am panning to buy a laptop (for heavy duty).
I have 3 options

1. Regular HDD (cheapest)
2. SSD+HDD(moderate)
3. ssd (Pricy)

I am inclined toward 2nd option (ssd+hdd) but my consern is that to use it I will have to install my OS in ssd and since ssd is limited I will have to install other programs in HDD. 
But from My experience I have seen visual studio, sql always need some storage in windows drive if you install them in other drive also.(On XP Machine)

Will I be able to suffice with 32 gb  ssd + hdd, if I need visual studion and sql server or should I only consider Hdd option. My os will be windows 8 if thats matter.

Comment: A 32 GB SSD is pushing it. Why that small? A 256 GB one can be had for under $200 these days...

Comment: for what exactly do you need SSD speeds?

Comment: This is a very open question with answers being very opinion based... What happens if you need to install new software which doesn't allow you to choose where to install it?

Comment: @Ratna could you please validate an answer to that question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to go for a bigger SSD, possibly even a Hybrid SSD. The reason is that a SSD's have a big problem: If you fill it with more than 75% of its capacity, the disk will become really slow, and you should avoid that at all costs. So 32 GB really is little for an SSD. I run windows 8.1 on a 60 GB SSD, but I only use that machine for watching videos , listening to music and a little bit of internet browsing, where all media is accessed through my network.

You'll really quickly fill your SSD so depending on your usage, 60 GB might even be on the low side, but is still feasible. A hybrid can be like 750 GB where it uses internal flash memory for specific files such as the OS. This gives you a much faster hdd than a normal hdd for launching the OS, but still the massive space.

Combining an SSD and HDD is not so much of an option, because it will really limit the choices of laptops you can use, and that will actually make the price more expensive. Probably enough to get a 60 GB SSD alone, which still would be my preferred option.

If you really don't have a budget for a higher SSD or Hybrid drive, option 1 is the best.

So long story short:
depending on your budget: regular HDD or an SSD/Hybrid of at least 60 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I usually recommend to my client this kind of setup :

- SSD 80 Gb (or 120)  => OS
- HDD 500 Gb (or better) => Documents and software

The [minimum disk space requirement for Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements) is 20 Gb, but I can tell 32 Gb are not sufficient. Indeed, you will have to download updates, you will have the [pagefile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/12/14/what-is-the-page-file-for-anyway.aspx) and the [Hiberfil.sys](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15140/what-is-hiberfil.sys-and-how-do-i-delete-it/) files. That kind of stuff take space on the system drive (depending of the amount of RAM you have).

You should also check that kind of requirement for specific software, as Visual Studio.

By the way, using a SSD as system disk is totally worth it ! The gain of performance is definitely amazing!